# How do I disable iframe live preview on wmd editor

Tags: javascript, wmd-editor

I want disable iframe from `<div class="wmd-preview"></div>` [wmd-editor](http://wmd-editor.com/demo)

Example when somebody post Youtube embed link, the video will not showing on live preview.

Let me know

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you are after, but you could just remove the `wmd-preview` class.